# Block matrix contractions

Tags: matrices, trace, block-matrices

Consider the square block matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{mn\times mn}$ having $n^2$ blocks denoted by $A_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}, i,j=1,...,n$. I need to compute the following contractions:

The block-trace
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}A_{ii},$$
and the trace of each block
$$\text{tr}(A_{ij}).$$

Suppose that I cannot access the individual elements of $A$, since I don't have the explicit representation of the matrix. The only way that I can obtain information from the matrix is by multiplying a vector $x \in\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ on the right $y=Ax$. Which vectors should I choose and how do I need to combine them in order to obtain these two contractions efficiently?

Comment: It might be useful to note that your "contractions" are [partial traces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_trace).

Comment: Found an article about an algorithm optimizing the computations avoiding multiplication by zero. http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S012918311750005X?journalCode=ijmpc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is useful to characterize the trace of an $n \times n$ matrix as
$$
\operatorname{tr}(M) = \sum_{i=1}^n e_i^TAe_i
$$
where $e_1,\dots,e_n$ are the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$ (actually, we can take them to be *any* orthonormal basis).

Let $\otimes$ denote the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).  Your partial traces can be expressed as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^n (e_i \otimes I_m)^TA(e_i \otimes I_m)\\
\pmatrix{
\operatorname{tr}A_{11} & \cdots & \operatorname{tr}A_{1n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\operatorname{tr} A_{n1} & \cdots & \operatorname{tr}A_{nn}
}= \sum_{j=1}^n (I_n \otimes e_j)^TA(I_n \otimes e_j)
$$
Where $I_n$ denotes the $n \times n$ identity matrix.